# supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange Not Working when React app is in iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, google-chrome-extension, supabase

I am using Supabase user authentication in a React app hosted at `https://example.com` that is running inside an `iframe` injected by a Chrome extension [`chrome-sidebar`](https://github.com/segmentio/chrome-sidebar) when the browser is on a different domain/website `https://google.com`.

By adding `console.log` calls into the React app and observing for them, I notice that the React effect is run once as expected, but `supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange` is never fired when the user logs in successfully.

```js
function App() {
  const [session, setSession] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSession(supabase.auth.session());
    console.log("session:", session);

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      console.log("supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange"); // THIS DOES NOT RUN WHEN USER LOGS IN
      setSession(session);
    });
  }, []);

...
```

❌ **Browser at `https://google.com`, iframe at `https://example.com`:**

1. `session` is `null` when `useEffect` first runs, as expected since the user is not logged in yet
2. `supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange` never runs on user login
3. `supabase.auth.token` is not found in Local Storage on user login

However, if we also run the React app directly by navigating a Chrome browser to `https://example.com`, everything works as expected:

✅ **Browser at `https://example.com`, no iframe:**

1. `supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange` fires and prints the `console.log` message
2. The session data is stored in `Storage > Local Storage > https://example.com` under the key `supabase.auth.token`

How can we get `supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange` to work when the React app is inside an `iframe`?

---

✅ **Browser and Iframe both at `https://example.com`:**

Both browser and iframe works as expected!

Comment: Have you managed to find a workaround?

Comment: @vwos Not yet. Are you experiencing the same problem?

Comment: I'm also injecting a React app in an iframe as a Chrome extension, but I'm not using `chrome-sidebar` (so just the local React app). I don't know if this also has the same problem (didn't get that far into the project yet), but you could give it a try if that's possible for you @gameveloster