# Supabase Auth: Google Oauth is succesful, but onAuthStateChange is not triggered

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, supabase, supabase-js

I'm building a Google slides add on. The DB operations are implemented using Supabase and the frontend using React.

I'm trying to use Supabase oauth to authenticate the user via Google.

Here's my code:

```js
const handleSignIn = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: 'google',
      options: {
        skipBrowserRedirect: true,
        redirectTo: 'https://<domain>.com/success',
      },
    });

    if (error || !data || !data.url) {
      console.error('Error signing in:', error);
      return;
    }

    // open google oauth consent screen in new tab
    // without this it tries to open the iframe inside the modal which Google doesn't allow
    // check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819128/supabase-auth-onauthstatechange-not-working-when-react-app-is-in-iframe
    window.open(data.url, '_blank');
  };
```

The user clicks on the link, and is able to sign in. Supabase creates a user identity in the `auth.users` table. However, I'm unable to get the details of the signed in user. In my top level component I have this:

```js
  const [session, setSession] = useState<Session | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    supabaseClient.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      console.log('got session', session);
      setSession(session);
    });

    supabaseClient.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      console.log('authChanged', event, session);
      setSession(session);
    });
  }, []);
```

The session is always null and I am only seeing 1 console log for `INITIAL_SESSION` which is null. I can't see any other auth state changes when the user signs in or out.

How do I get the logged in user's auth state changes?

Comment: After completing the Google sign in on Google's page, where is the user taken to on the browser?

Comment: I see. That is the expected behavior. You will not see an active session in the original page unless the page is refreshed. You should however see a session on the page that the user lands after signing in.

Comment: how do you extract session info from the page user lands on? is there any documentation i can refer to?

Comment: You can get the session with `await supabase.auth.getSession()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that the page I was routing to was stripping the access token before Supabase could process it